# NOT operator in redis scan command when pattern matching

Tags: regex, redis

Consider these commands:

First i create a sample trip as hash:

```
HMSET trip:1734 id 1734 start 08:35 end 09:30
```

Then I need to store some route points for the trip, I do it with lists like this:

```
RPUSH trip:1734:routes 22444.345566,32.875553 77.3,44.3
```

Now I need to retrieve only trips (list of trips) without route part, how I can do that?

I tried:

```
SCAN 0 MATCH trip:*[^:routes]
```

and it is working well.

But why does this not work?

```
SCAN 0 MATCH trip:*[^:*]
```

Comment: Redis' pattern matching is very basic and certainly not RegEx but more glob-like. Specifically, this form of "NOT" does not work and the square brackets are interpreted as "matches on of the following characters".

Comment: Thanks for your attention, So what is your suggestion for this scenario

Comment: That depends - do you need to run this "query" often & fast?

Comment: Negated character classes are supported, just not with strings like ":routes" or with ":*" like you're trying. See here: https://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: A workaround would be to arrange your keys so that they can be prefixed-matched, which is suitable for redis globbing rules. e.g. `triproutes:1734` would be your keyname for the list of route points for trip ID 1734, then use the scan pattern `trip:*` to exclude the routes.